# How establish connection to database? for person who get my files

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have written an app with java (eclipse) that uses the database created in MySQL Workbench.
How can I distribute it (send to some other person)?

For Java files I will send the jar files, but how the app will get connected to the database (I will send the exported tables in Self-Contained File)?
Since in java code I'm using for connection the localhost, username, password that I don't think will work for the person who compiles my files (because he uses a different computer), am I right, what should I do? Is it enough to send jar files and exported tables to Self-Contained File?

Comment: Unless you're using an embedded database, sending database contents is usually quite a poor idea.

Comment: *I will sent the exported tables in Self-Contained File* - why are you initially using a DB?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Because I'm working on some database that I have created

Comment: If this is just for "show-and-tell", open free mysql hosting eg. https://www.db4free.net/, insert Your data there, create connection and You're good to go. Send/upload Your jar file to some of free clouds google.

Comment: @Kayaman Why a poor idea? It is some data that I have created. What do you mean by "embedded database"  how it can be done?

Comment: @Kovacic It helps, thanks!!

Comment: Nice to help...

Comment: @student welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Kovacic Am I getting it right, by using some hosting,  there is no need to send  mysql file?

Answer (score -1):

Export your tables to sql file and send the sql file if the data is less.

Comment: I have exported the tables to a single file (workbench call it 'Self-Contained File')...but what the connection itself? I established connection in java code that uses some localhost, would it work for others who receives my files too?

Comment: No one can pass the connection. the other person should use your sql file import it in to his/her database. But why you downvoted the answer is what iam wondering thats how its is and thats how people do it. Or you should use same common database

Comment: I didn't downvoted ( up/down option only open for one with at list '15 reputation' mine is 1)....So that person (to whom i send my file) must enter (in java code) there own server name, port name? otherwise how it will work for him?

Comment: Hey @student. I explained this is just a test DB. I don't know nothing about Your code, this is just a FREE service where You could set your data for test. Log into db4free.net, with your authentication, import sql into box that is related for that. You now have a valid sql da structure in mysql tables, procedures and whatever(if everything is exported correctly). In connection string You should set up connection to this service, search for connection string for mysql. I was just telling how to expose your db without sending any files about sql. This is just for testing/learning/presentation.

Comment: Your connection string is secured in code, and it holds all necessary to connect to db:

example:

    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    String connection = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YourDBName";

    String user = "root";

    String password = "root";

    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connection, user, password);
    if (!con.isClosed()) {
      con.close();
    }

Comment: @student what is your actual use of this code. Its a learning project or your actual professional work. If its your learning project you can use free services as Kovaic said or let the other person install his local mysql database